# While export to excel in laravel 4.2 from database

Tags: php, laravel

Blade file:

```
<div class="container">
   <a href="{{ url::to('exportTo/xls') }}"><button class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></span> Export to xls</button></a>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public function exportTo($type)
{

    $data = locations::get(['location_name','location_email'])->toArray();
           // dd($data);

    return Excel::create('export_to_excel_example', function($excel) use ($data) {
        $excel->sheet('mySheet', function($sheet) use ($data)
        {
            $sheet->fromArray($data);
        });
    })->download($type);
}
```

Route file:

```
Route::get('exportTo/{type}', 'CustomerController@exportTo');
```

While exporting to excel in laravel 4.2 and it is redirected to index page, when i click on Export to xls link in blade file.

Comment: There isn't a Laravel 4.8. Version four stopped at 4.2.